# Nvim function to compile file in terminal

Tags: neovim, functions, terminal-buffer

```
function! RunCppFile(filename, filedir)
    let compile = "g++ " . a:filename . " -o " . a:filedir . "/a.exe" 
    :terminal 
    <i>
endfunction
nnoremap <C-L> :call RunCppFile(expand("%:p"), expand("%:p:h"))<CR>
```

I want it to open a terminal buffer, run the `compile` command, and run a.exe as well. I'm having trouble doing that.

Solution!

```lua
function! RunCppFile(filename, filedir)
  let compile = 'g++ ' . a:filename . ' -o ' . a:filedir . '/a.exe && ' . a:filedir . "/a.exe" 
  :terminal 
  :startinsert
  call feedkeys(compile)
  let key = nvim_replace_termcodes("<CR>", v:true, v:false, v:true)
  call nvim_feedkeys(key, 'm', v:false)
endfunction
nnoremap <C-L> :call RunCppFile(expand("%:p"), expand("%:p:h"))<CR>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can pass the shell commands to the terminal buffer with `:h chansend()`. Here is an example:

```
function! RunCppFile(filename, filedir)
  let cmd_compile = 'g++ ' . a:filename . ' -o ' . a:filedir . '\a.exe'
  let cmd_runexe = '.\a.exe'
  new
  let term_channel_id = termopen('cmd.exe')
  call chansend(term_channel_id, [cmd_compile, cmd_runexe, ''])
endfunction
nnoremap <C-w>r :call RunCppFile(expand("%:p"), expand("%:p:h"))<CR>
```

Sadly, there is an [Windows-specific bug](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/18501) in neovim core that behaves incorrectly when sending commands through `:h chansend()`. The function above will work fine in *Nix systems (provided you adapt the executable extension and path separator accordingly), but won't work in Windows, which is presumably what OP is using.

In a slightly less sad news, there is a [working fix](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/19315) for this bug. It has been approved. Hopefully it will be merged soon. Until then I encourage OP to patch it in for themself if at all able to. I'm the author of the patch and have been using it without any issue since a couple months.

Comment: Splitting is already done by the terminal command

Comment: In regular Vim, at least, it is

Comment: I know. But look at the question title

Comment: Sorry if I didn't elaborate more in my question. I would like for me to still see the terminal after the command was executed. So basically after I use the shortcut, I want it to open the terminal, compile the program, and also run ./a.exe which needs input. Sorry for not elaborating further.

Comment: Furthermore, execute doesn't allow me to supply my own input.

Comment: Thank you! I found a way to get around the chansend bug with feedkeys().